# Is there a body animator I can use to demonstrate exercise movements?

Tags: calisthenics, calculation, movements

I just discovered a nice calisthenic exercise that I feel is better shown than described. Is there a human body animator where I can move it, record it, and then share it?

Comment: It is asking for a software package not in the context of n active fitness program.